# Entity Framework 4 Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, entity-framework

I'm been looking around and trying to see if the Entity Framework 4 will run under Visual Studio 2008, but can;t find any references to it.

Can you get EF4 working on VS2008?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the [ADO.NET Entity Framework Team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2009/05/11/update-on-the-entity-framework-in-net-4-and-visual-studio-2010.aspx), they have stated the the EF 4 is explicitly targeted for .NET4 and Visual Studio 2010.
So, I would say no, it's not possible.