# Can I use entity framework with Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, entity-framework

Can I use entity framework (latest version)  with vs.net 08?

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727726/entity-framework-4-visual-studio-2008

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Entity Framework shipped with .NET 3.5 SP1. But that's not the latest version (4.1 at this time). And for that you would need VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Entity Framework 4.0 (or 4.1) because it requires .NET 4.0. You'll need Visual Studio 2010 for that.

Answer (score 1):

According to Scott Guthrie, yes:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/05/12/visual-studio-2008-and-net-framework-3-5-service-pack-1-beta.aspx

CORRECTION: I missed that you said "latest," and as others stated, no, you'll need the latest and greatest VS to use EF4.

Answer (score 1):

No you would need VS2010 or SharpDevelop.